# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark in black?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any easy way to change the color of the "UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark" from standard blue to black?
Or do i need to make a subclass of uitableviewcell and insert a imageview myself?

Thanks :-)
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of doing this.

I ended up implementing a complete custom view for my accessoryView. It also makes it easier to change it upon user interaction and to decide the tappable area, which I often find way to small. I guess you could do with just a button if you have no need for different views.

I did a customView, placed a transparent button inside it. This view I add to the cell:

```
CustomDisclosureArea *disArea = [[CustomDisclosureArea alloc] init];
[disArea setFrame:CGRectMake(280.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 71.0f)];
[disArea setTag:DISCLOSURE_ID];
[disArea.emptyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonHandler:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //this the button inside the view.
[cell.contentView addSubview:disArea];
[disArea switchToState:AreaStateBlank]; //I can set it to different states (blank, checkmark, empty etc.
[disArea release];
```

Now the method that gets called when the accessoryView is tapped is a little special because we need to know which cell was tapped.

```
- (void) cellButtonHandler:(id)sender event:(id)event {

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
}
```

But You end up with an NSIndexPath, which is the same as you would get in a didSelectRow or and accessoryButtonTapped method.

Hope this helps if You decide to make a custom accessoryView:)

Comment: thank you a lot. 
Parts like these make me wonder why apple does not eat their own food and populates the accessoryView when i set the style. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but it might be possible to simply interrogate the `accessoryView` property of the cell and find the checkmark and replace it with another image (it's almost certainly an image.) I think that cell style is just a default style tablecell with an image cell that holds the checkmark.

Comment: accessoryView is nil if you don't explicitly set it by yourself.
if set, then the  accessoryType is ignored.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping it might be more simple.